# Why zsh shell is running Python 3 while bash is running Python 2 on Mac OS

Tags: macos, bash, python, git, zsh

I just bought a new MacBook running macOS Catalina version 10.15.5.

After installing Anaconda, Homebrew, Git, etc, I've noticed that the shell I'm running is not **bash**, rather it's **zsh**—which i'm clueless about.

Now everything i've installed worked fine with zsh; except when I tried to configure the terminal for better visualization when using git using udacity's terminal config (can be found [here](http://yelangya3826850.github.io/2017/04/16/Udacity-Version_Control/)).

My trials to overcome this are as follows:

- I've used `chsh -s /bin/bash` to force my default shell to be bash instead. Now the configuration works fine, but I cannot use the `pip` command or open `jupyter notebook` directly from the terminal.
- I have tried to figure out the root cause, and it turns out that bash is running Python 2.7 while zsh is running Python 3.7.
- I then tried to install Python 3.7 using `brew install python` and it installed Python 3.7 but still `python --version` shows Python 2.7.

Note that Anaconda is installed in my home directory but python3, homebrew are installed in `/usr/local/bin/`. Should I remove anaconda from home directory and place it somewhere else? And if this is the case, why it is working for zsh then?

Comment: You need to fix your bash `PATH` and maybe other environment variables.

Comment: @DavidPostill How to fix my `PATH`?

Comment: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)